# WordPress stats: OWA plugin overhead in the future

Tags: plugins, performance, statistics

I've found a really promising stats plugin, [Open Web Analytics](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/owa/). It has everything I need, also, it is self-hosted, without tracking cookies. The only thing I'm getting worried about is the overhead both in performance both in database size.

Does anyone have experience with this plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't used this specific solution, but any self-hosted analytics in general should be considered potentially huge resource hog:

- every async action in WordPress is effectively another WP core load, so if tracking code makes even one additional async request to back-end it effectively doubles the load;
- stat logging by nature cannot be cached;
- stat logging by nature needs database writes, which are much more performance-hungry than reads.

Hosted analytics solution are popular exactly because analytics comes with performance challenges.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but they also come with tracking cookies. Of all hosted analytics, which one would you suggest?

Comment: @petermolnar what is your concern about cookies? It is kinda essential for tracking repeat visits and such. From hosted solutions Google Analytics is one of the most popular, but there are plenty of alternatives around.

Comment: privacy? :) But really, I don't like the idea that third-party providers are informed about every single visit even inside my own site.